# How to replace certain values in a column based on a certain condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following `df`

```
col_1   col_2
1   1
1   2
1   3
1   6
1   8
1   11
1   12
1   19
1   24
1   1
1   1
1   2
1   2
1   3 
1   3
2   1
2   2
2   4
2   6
2   7
2   11
2   13
2   16
2   19
2   1
2   2
2   3
```

I would like to do kind of groupby on `col_1` and replace the values 1, 2, 3 that occur **after** 19 in the `col_2` and change them with 25, 26, 27.

**Expected Output:**

```
col_1   col_2
1   1
1   2
1   3
1   6
1   8
1   11
1   12
1   19
1   24
1   25
1   25
1   26
1   26
1   27
1   27
2   1
2   2
2   4
2   6
2   7
2   11
2   13
2   16
2   19
2   25
2   26
2   27
```

I would like to know how can this be done using pandas.

Thanks

**Edit 1:**

My real `df`

```
ContextID   BacksGas_Flow_sccm  StepID
7289973 1.953125    1
7289973 2.05078125  2
7289973 2.05078125  2
7289973 2.05078125  2
7289973 1.953125    2
7289973 1.7578125   2
7289973 1.7578125   2
7289973 1.85546875  2
7289973 1.7578125   2
7289973 9.08203125  5
7289973 46.19140625 5
7289973 46.19140625 5
7289973 46.19140625 5
7289973 46.19140625 5
7289973 46.6796875  5
7289973 46.6796875  5
7289973 46.6796875  5
7289973 46.6796875  5
7289973 46.6796875  5
7289973 46.6796875  5
7289973 46.6796875  5
7289973 46.6796875  5
7289973 46.6796875  5
7289973 46.6796875  5
7289973 46.6796875  7
7289973 46.6796875  7
7289973 46.6796875  7
7289973 46.6796875  12
7289973 46.6796875  12
7289973 46.6796875  12
7289973 46.6796875  12
7289973 46.6796875  12
7289973 46.6796875  12
7289973 46.6796875  12
7289973 46.6796875  15
7289973 46.6796875  15
7289973 46.6796875  16
7289973 46.6796875  16
7289973 46.6796875  17
7289973 25.09765625 19
7289973 45.99609375 19
7289973 59.08203125 19
7289973 61.81640625 19
7289973 62.59765625 19
7289973 63.671875   19
7289973 65.625  19
7289973 66.69921875 19
7289973 67.3828125  19
7289973 67.3828125  19
7289973 67.67578125 19
7289973 68.26171875 19
7289973 69.04296875 19
7289973 69.82421875 19
7289973 69.82421875 19
7289973 70.8984375  19
7289973 70.8984375  19
7289973 70.8984375  19
7289973 70.8984375  19
7289973 71.6796875  19
7289973 71.6796875  19
7289973 72.55859375 19
7289973 72.55859375 19
7289973 72.55859375 19
7289973 72.55859375 19
7289973 72.55859375 19
7289973 72.55859375 19
7289973 73.33984375 19
7289973 73.33984375 19
7289973 73.33984375 19
7289973 74.12109375 19
7289973 74.12109375 19
7289973 74.12109375 19
7289973 73.2421875  19
7289973 73.2421875  19
7289973 74.0234375  19
7289973 74.0234375  19
7289973 74.0234375  19
7289973 74.0234375  19
7289973 74.0234375  19
7289973 74.0234375  19
7289973 74.0234375  19
7289973 74.0234375  19
7289973 74.0234375  19
7289973 74.90234375 19
7289973 74.90234375 19
7289973 74.12109375 19
7289973 74.12109375 19
7289973 74.12109375 19
7289973 74.12109375 19
7289973 74.12109375 19
7289973 75          19
7289973 75          19
7289973 75          19
7289973 74.21875    19
7289973 74.21875    19
7289973 74.21875    19
7289973 75          19
7289973 75          19
7289973 75          19
7289973 75          19
7289973 74.12109375 19
7289973 74.12109375 19
7289973 74.12109375 19
7289973 74.90234375 19
7289973 6.4453125   24
7289973 3.515625    24
7289973 2.5390625   24
7289973 2.05078125  24
7289973 2.05078125  24
7289973 2.05078125  24
7289973 1.953125    24
7289973 1.953125    24
7289973 1.953125    24
7289973 1.953125    24
7289973 2.05078125  24
7289973 1.85546875  24
7289973 1.85546875  24
7289973 1.85546875  24
7289973 1.85546875  24
7289973 1.85546875  24
7289973 2.05078125  24
7289973 1.953125    24
7289973 1.953125    24
7289973 1.7578125   24
7289973 1.66015625  24
7289973 1.7578125   24
7289973 1.7578125   24
7289973 1.7578125   24
7289973 1.85546875  24
7289973 1.85546875  24
7289973 1.953125    24
7289973 1.953125    24
7289973 1.953125    24
7289973 1.953125    24
7289973 1.953125    24
7289973 1.7578125   24
7289973 1.85546875  24
7289973 1.85546875  24
7289973 1.85546875  24
7289973 1.7578125   24
7289973 1.85546875  24
7289973 1.85546875  24
7289973 1.7578125   24
7289973 1.7578125   1
7289973 1.85546875  1
7289973 1.85546875  1
7289973 1.85546875  2
7289973 1.7578125   2
7289973 1.953125    2
7289973 1.953125    2
7289973 1.85546875  2
7289973 1.85546875  3
7289973 1.85546875  3
7289973 1.85546875  3
7289973 1.953125    3
7289973 1.85546875  3
7289973 1.953125    3
7289973 1.85546875  3
7289973 1.7578125   3
7289973 1.85546875  3
7289973 1.85546875  3
7289973 1.7578125   3
7289973 1.85546875  3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your real DataFrame, you can do the following:

```
df['StepID'] = df.groupby('ContextID')['StepID'].apply(
    lambda x: x + (x < x.shift(1)).cumsum()*24)

print(df.tail(25))
```

Output:

```
     ContextID  BacksGas_Flow_sccm  StepID
138    7289973            1.855469      24
139    7289973            1.757812      24
140    7289973            1.855469      24
141    7289973            1.855469      24
142    7289973            1.757812      24
143    7289973            1.757812      25
144    7289973            1.855469      25
145    7289973            1.855469      25
146    7289973            1.855469      26
147    7289973            1.757812      26
148    7289973            1.953125      26
149    7289973            1.953125      26
150    7289973            1.855469      26
151    7289973            1.855469      27
152    7289973            1.855469      27
153    7289973            1.855469      27
154    7289973            1.953125      27
155    7289973            1.855469      27
156    7289973            1.953125      27
157    7289973            1.855469      27
158    7289973            1.757812      27
159    7289973            1.855469      27
160    7289973            1.855469      27
161    7289973            1.757812      27
162    7289973            1.855469      27
```

P.S. In your sample data there is only one `ContextID`, but I'm assuming there might be others as well in the full dataset, so I've added `groupby`

**Update**: the following is if you only need to increment values after `24` for each `ContextID` once by 24 (I'm saving new values to `StepID_new` column to show before-and-after the transformation):

```
x = [1,2,3,19,19,24,1,1,2,2,3,3,2,3,1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'ContextID': np.repeat([1,2], len(x)),
                   'StepID': x * 2})

df['StepID_new'] = df['StepID'] + df.groupby('ContextID')['StepID'].transform(
    lambda x: ((x==24).cumsum() > 0).shift(1, fill_value=0) * 25)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    ContextID  StepID  StepID_new
0           1       1           1
1           1       2           2
2           1       3           3
3           1      19          19
4           1      19          19
5           1      24          24
6           1       1          26
7           1       1          26
8           1       2          27
9           1       2          27
10          1       3          28
11          1       3          28
12          1       2          27
13          1       3          28
14          1       1          26
15          2       1           1
16          2       2           2
17          2       3           3
18          2      19          19
19          2      19          19
20          2      24          24
21          2       1          26
22          2       1          26
23          2       2          27
24          2       2          27
25          2       3          28
26          2       3          28
27          2       2          27
28          2       3          28
29          2       1          26
```

Comment: Worked! Yes, you were right in assuming that I have multiple `ContextID`s. Thanks a ton! Could you please explain in short what exactly is it doing?

Comment: Sure, so basically it's searching for records where the following `StepID` is lower than current (like when it drops from 24 to 1), and using `cumsum` multiplied by 24 to add 24 to each of the following records (and if it drops again it will add 48 etc., so you'll have monotonic `StepID`s)

Comment: ah ok. Thanks for the explanation. But I have a question: when you said if it drops again, it'll add 48 etc.. But I actually don't prefer to have that. I want the values only to be 25, 26 or 27. Can this be achieved? Thanks

Comment: I mean, once 19 is crossed, if the 1, 2, 3 come in any sequence, it must be only changed to 25, 26, 27. For instance if the sequence for one ContextID is: 19, 19, 24, 1,1,2,2,3,3,2,3,1; it must be converted to: 19, 19, 24, 25, 25, 26, 26, 27, 27, 26, 27, 25

Comment: OK, sure, but why do you add 24 to 1, 2, and 3s here, but not to 24, which also comes after 19?

Comment: @zeeman: Please have a look at the update in my answer with a sequence of `StepID`s similar to what you posted above in the comments

Comment: That's because I am doing kind of an anomaly detection and the StepID ranges from 1 to 24, but the StepIDs after 24 (usually 1,2,3 repeat themselves) are of interest to me

Comment: It throws the following error now: `TypeError: shift() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fill_value'`

Comment: Is your `pd.__version__` above 0.24.0?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192733/discussion-between-zeeman-and-perl).

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to create a dictionary to [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) the values in `col_2`. In order to replace only those that appear after a `19`, [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), check equality and take the `cumsum` to perform boolean indexation on the dataframe:

```
map_ = {1:25, 2:26, 3:27}
cs = df.col_2.eq(19).groupby(df.col_1).cumsum()
update = df.loc[cs].col_2.replace(map_)
df.loc[update.index, 'col_2'] = update

 col_1  col_2
0       1      1
1       1      2
2       1      3
3       1      6
4       1      8
5       1     11
6       1     12
7       1     19
8       1     25
9       1     26
10      1     27
11      2      1
12      2      2
13      2      4
14      2      6
15      2      7
16      2     11
17      2     13
18      2     16
19      2     19
20      2     25
21      2     26
22      2     27
```

Comment: This is exactly how I first thought to do this.  Now I'll have to think of another way (-:

Comment: Hey @yatu, 2 things: 1) The last line seems to be running forever. Maybe since I have a big df of size (210000, 4)?   2) I edited the `df` in the question. Could you kindly have a look at it once? Thanks

Comment: I tried implementing it to my original df, and it somehow is replacing the top 1, 2, 3 for my original dataset. I have added my original df here. groupby needs to be done on the`ContextID` column and the `stepID` column is kind of the `Col_2` @yatu

Answer (score 0):

My try:

```
def fill19(x):
    # x.shift()==19 marks all 1's after 19's
    # rolling(3) marks three numbers after 19's
    filters = (x.shift()==19).rolling(3).sum().fillna(0).astype(bool)
    x[filters] += 24
    return x

df.col2 = df.groupby('col_1').col_2.apply(fill19)

0      1
1      2
2      3
3      6
4      8
5     11
6     12
7     19
8     25
9     26
10    27
11     1
12     2
13     4
14     6
15     7
16    11
17    13
18    16
19    19
20    25
21    26
22    27
Name: col_2, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below for loop, it does what is required in your case:

```
for i in df['col_1'].unique():
     ix = np.argwhere((df['col_1'] == i) & (df['col_2'] == 19 ))
     df.loc[ix[0][0]+1, 'col_2'] = 25
     df.loc[ix[0][0]+2, 'col_2'] = 26
     df.loc[ix[0][0]+3, 'col_2'] = 27
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Old school looping

```
map_ = {1: 25, 2: 26, 3: 27}

d = {}  # Tracks if 19 has been seen yet

for i, c1, c2 in df.itertuples():

    if d.setdefault(c1, False):
        df.at[i, 'col_2'] = map_.get(c2, c2)

    d[c1] |= c2 == 19
```

---

#### Using `np.logigcal_or`

```
m = df.col_2.eq(19)
m = m.groupby(df.col_1).transform(np.logical_or.accumulate) ^ m
df.assign(col_2=df.col_2 + m * 24)

    col_1  col_2
0       1      1
1       1      2
2       1      3
3       1      6
4       1      8
5       1     11
6       1     12
7       1     19
8       1     25
9       1     26
10      1     27
11      2      1
12      2      2
13      2      4
14      2      6
15      2      7
16      2     11
17      2     13
18      2     16
19      2     19
20      2     25
21      2     26
22      2     27
```